# Can remove liquidity manually but not with removeLiquidityETH, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

I am developing a token using `ganache`/`brownie`. As the title says, if I try and use `removeLiquidityETH` to test removing liquidity tokens, for example like this

```
pair.approve(pair_address, lp_balance, {'from':accounts[0]})

router.removeLiquidityETH(my_token.address,lp_balance, 0,0, accounts[0], int(time.time())+60, {'from': accounts[0]})
```

Then I get an error
`IUniswapV2Router02.removeLiquidityETH confirmed (ds-math-sub-underflow)`

and I do not see the ETH back in `accounts[0]`.

However, looking at how `removeLiquidityETH` works I can implement each step manually

```
pair.approve(pair_address, lp_balance, {'from':accounts[0]})

pair.transferFrom(accounts[0], pair_address, lp_balance, {'from': pair_address})

tx = pair.burn(accounts[0], {'from': pair_address})
    
interface.IWETH(router.WETH()).withdraw(tx.events['Burn']['amount1'], {'from':accounts[0]})
```

And everything works as intended with my `ETH` and `MyToken` balances being transferred back to `accounts[0]`.

I think the error is somewhere in `approve` or the transaction params `{'from'}` but I have tried every combination I can think of with `pair.approve` `router.approve` and `my_token.approve` and I still get the same error.

Does anyone have an example of how to use `removeLiquidityETH` properly? I have no issues with `addLiquidityETH`, in which I just use `MyToken` to `approve` the `router` spending.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/#removeliquidityeth)

> msg.sender should have already given the router an allowance of at least liquidity on the pool.

It doesn't seem like you're giving `router` an allowance to spend your liquidity tokens.

Comment: `pair.approve(router_address, lp_balance, {'from':accounts[0]})` still fails

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `accounts[0]` is the address holding the LP tokens. The issue seems to be that you are approving the pair contract as spender of the LP tokens whereas you should be approving the router as spender.

Replace this:

```
pair.approve(pair_address, balance, {'from':accounts[0]})
```

By this:

```
pair.approve(router_address, lp_balance, {'from':accounts[0]})
```

Comment: This still fails. It fails in the `transfer` function - again it looks like the sender does not have enough balance to send; ie. the right approval has not been made.

Comment: I just edited my answer. I replaced balance by lp_balance. If it stills does not work, please edit your question to include where you define all the variables that you use (pair_address, balance, lp_balance, router_address, etc.)

Comment: Apologies, this was a typo. The variable is `lp_balance = pair.balanceOf(accounts[0])` ie. the balance of the lp tokens in `accounts[0]`. The issue is not with variable names, but with incorrect approval, though I don't understand why as I can follow the correct approval flow in the manual version/.

Comment: If your variables are correct, I don't know what's the issue with the information you provided. Try to include more information. Maybe the error that you get and more of your code.

Comment: I solved it. I need to use the `SupportingFeeOnTransferTokens` variation of the `removeLiquidityETH` function. Out of interest do you know how to the uniswap front end knows which of the two (non-fee and supporting fee) functions it has to call when someone tries to remove liquidity on the website?

Comment: Ah, your token had fees on transfer! I don't know how the interface knows the token has fees (and even IF it knows that there are fees).

Comment: FYI, you can award the bounty manually if you want. Otherwise, it is lost.